# Facebook login doesn't work even with right site url

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have my web application deployed in tomcat. Application loads fine with the URL:
http://domain.com/portal-app/ *(domain.com=10.124.23.33:8081 i couldn't enter ip:port in url.)* i have also pasted the same URL in my app settings page. 
But still i get the error on console while loading the home page. I don't get js alerts too. When i click on "login" button and enter username and pwd, it just throws the same message in the facebook pop-up window. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

> "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs >>is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or >>>the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."

I had several times verified the URL in app settings. Both the application url that i use in browser and Facebook are same. Rather i just copy pasted the url. 
Here is the code

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

//Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "./js/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '488834651123456',
        channelUrl : 'http://domain/portal-app/channel.html',
    status     : true,
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        alert(response.status);
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          alert("hi");
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    alert("hi");
                } else {
                    // The person cancelled the login dialog
                }
            }, {scope: 'user_about_me,user_birthday,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,read_stream'});
        }else {             
              FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        alert("hi");
                    } else {
                        // The person cancelled the login dialog
                    }
                }, {scope: 'user_about_me,user_birthday,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,read_stream'});                 
        }           
      });
};

</script>
    <fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `channelUrl` is missing the `.com` and should be `http://domain.com/portal-app/channel.html` in your init function.

Comment: nope, the actual channel url is 10.124.23.33:8081 since the editor doesn't allow me to enter the full address (http://IP) i had it as 'domain'. please read through my 2nd line.